# Double sort and ADDING duplicates based on quantity

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of items, the quantity of each item, and the type.  I would like to sort by the type, then alphabetically, while duplicating the name of the item based on the quantity.

So a range like this:

```
|  Item  |Quantity|  Type   |
|--------|--------|---------|
|Onion   |      1 |Vegetable|
|Lettuce |      5 |Vegetable|
|Tomato  |      1 |Vegetable|
|Cherry  |      3 |Fruit    |
|Apple   |      1 |Fruit    |
|Broccoli|      1 |Vegetable|
```

becomes this (in a different location not affecting original range):

```
|--------|--------|---------|
|Apple   |      1 |Fruit    |
|Cherry  |      1 |Fruit    |
|Cherry  |      2 |Fruit    |
|Cherry  |      3 |Fruit    |
|Broccoli|      1 |Vegetable|
|Lettuce |      1 |Vegetable|
|Lettuce |      2 |Vegetable|
|Lettuce |      3 |Vegetable|
|Lettuce |      4 |Vegetable|
|Lettuce |      5 |Vegetable|
|Onion   |      1 |Vegetable|
|Tomato  |      1 |Vegetable|
```

There could be up to 50 rows in the original range, and up to 20 different types.  Quantity would not go over 50, but 90% of the time it would be just 1.

I do not know how to go about making this happen.  I've used Index/Match before, and Offset, but this is beyond my abilities.

I'm using Office 365 (ver 2208) if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data are in columns A:C as per your example, use the below macro:

```
Sub MacroVBA()
Dim workingSheet As Worksheet
Dim newSheet As Worksheet
Dim originalRange As Range
Dim newRange As Range
Dim item As Range
Dim quantity As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set workingSheet = ActiveSheet
Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

Set originalRange = workingSheet.Range("A1:C" & workingSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

originalRange.Sort key1:=originalRange.Columns(3), order1:=xlAscending, _
                    key2:=originalRange.Columns(1), order2:=xlAscending, _
                    Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

originalRange.Rows(1).Copy newSheet.Range("A1")

Set newRange = newSheet.Range("A2")

For Each item In originalRange.Rows
    On Error Resume Next
    quantity = CInt(item.Cells(1, 2).Value)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    For i = 1 To quantity
        newRange.Value = item.Cells(1, 1).Value
        newRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = i
        newRange.Offset(0, 2).Value = item.Cells(1, 3).Value
        Set newRange = newRange.Offset(1, 0)
    Next i
Next item

End Sub
```

Go to sheet where your data is and then execute the macro. The sorted data as per your request then will be pasted in a new sheet. Check this out and if you want to edit something, tell me.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.  I appreciate the response.  But I was hoping to avoid VBA for this spreadsheet, and use worksheet functions only.  I do know VBA pretty well, and sometimes us Access as a database with Excel as the frontend.  But I am restricted to no VBA for this particular spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//change next line to reflect data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Produce"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Item", type text}, {"Quantity", Int64.Type}, {"Type", type text}}),

//Duplicate the rows according to Quantity
    #"Duplicate Rows" = List.Accumulate({0..Table.RowCount(#"Changed Type")-1},{},(state, current)=> 
        state & List.Repeat({#"Changed Type"{current}}, #"Changed Type"{current}[Quantity])),

//Convert list of records to table and expand.
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(#"Duplicate Rows", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"Item", "Quantity", "Type"}),

//Remove the Quantity Column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Column",{"Quantity"}),

//Group by Item and add Index column to each sub group
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Item"}, {
        {"Add Index", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_,"Index",1), type table [Item=text, Type=text, Index=Int64.Type]}
        }),

//Remove the Item column and expand the grouped tables
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Item"}),
    #"Expanded Add Index" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Add Index", {"Item", "Type", "Index"}),

//Set the Column Order
    #"Reorder Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded Add Index",{
        "Item","Index","Type"}),

//Set the sorted order
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Reorder Columns",{{"Type", Order.Ascending}, {"Item", Order.Ascending}, {"Index", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: I've never used Power Query before, but this is interesting.  I will have to play around with it and learn it.  No disrespect to the other response, but I was trying to avoid VBA.  I know VBA pretty well, but can't use it here.  Does Power Query throw up roadblocks and disclaimer buttons like VBA does?

Comment: @kevrish you will need to try that in your own environment.